# Error 500 with .ashx handlers

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a problem to publish my site on an online server.

Locally the site works perfectly!

All pages with aspx extension work well, the problem is in handlers with .ashx extension when using ajax.

To upload an image I get in the error console of firefox 500.

As the error alert ("Error:" + err.statusText) shows **Internal Server Error.**

Sending the code below:

```
$("#Button1").click(function (event){
            var uploadfiles = $("#MultipleFilesUpload").get(0);
            var uploadedfiles = uploadfiles.files;
            if (uploadedfiles.length == 0) {
                notificacaoAviso("Selecione uma imagem!");
            } else {
                var fromdata = new FormData();
                for (var i = 0; i < uploadedfiles.length; i++) {
                    fromdata.append(uploadedfiles[i].name, uploadedfiles[i]);
                }

                var choice = {};
                alert("sim 1");
                choice.url = "../handlers/UploadHandlerUser.ashx";

                choice.type = "POST";
                alert("sim 2");
                choice.data = fromdata;
                choice.contentType = false;
                choice.processData = false;
                choice.success = function (result) {





notificacaoAlteracaoSucesso(result);



     };
        choice.error = function (err) { alert("Error:"+err.statusText); };
        $.ajax(choice);
           event.preventDefault();

    }
});
```

Comment: Have you assigned the right file permissions to the upload folder?

Answer (score 0):

I just increased the size of the files in the web.config!

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" requestValidationMode="4.0" />
```

Give more permissions? Published on the website locally works fine ... the site published an online server is not ...